# How to search a whole word string stored in a data frame within a list in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a pandas data frame which has a column 'title' and I have a list called my_list.
I want to search each value from df['title'] in my_list and get the list index. df['title'] needs to be a whole word and not part of any word.

Regex seemed to be the obvious solution. I am storing one value at a time from df['title'] to i to match, concatenating '\b' before and after the string to get the whole word only, I am getting no match even though the word exists.

```
for i in df['title']:
    print(i)
    x = ('\b'+i+'\b')
    print(x)
    print([s for s in my_list if re.search(x, s)])
    print(len(i))
    print(len(x))
```

The output that I get is

```
ITEM
ITE
[]
4
6
ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE
ITEM_NUMBER_TYP
[]
16
18
.........and so on
```

I am unable to figure out why ITEM becomes ITE and when I try

```
x = ('\b'+i+' \b')
#added a white space before the second '\b' to get the whole word
```

I get the following output:

```
ITEM
ITEM
[]
4
7
ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE
ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE
[]
16
19
......and so on
```

content of my_list:

```
print(my_list)
Output:
['ITEM_XFORM_IND IS NOT NULL',
 'ITEM IS NOT NULL',
 'ITEM_LEVEL IS NOT NULL']

#I want for i = 'ITEM', just 'ITEM IS NOT NULL' to match, not the rest.
```

Comment: so my list is a list of words?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yaa, each element is string (sentence).

Answer (score -1):

Python interprets  [`\b`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-26) as backspace, try `r'\b'`